# jQuery - sending data and taking the datas in php side

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

this is my html form

```
{foreach value=artist2 from=$artist}

                  <form name=form1 method=post action=action_page.php onsubmit='return validate(this)'>

                <br />

                <span class="checkArtist" id="hide_{$artist2.MOVIE_ID}-{$artist2.PERSON_ID}-374"><input type="checkbox" name="artist[]" value="{$artist2.MOVIE_ID}-{$artist2.PERSON_ID}-374"  />{$artist2.NAME_SURNAME}<br /></span>


                {/foreach}
                <p align="right">
                <a style="float: right" ><br />
                    <input type="button" name="checkArtistButton" value="Seçilenleri Sil" onclick="deleteData('artist[]');" id="ajaxCheckbox" /></a></p>
                <br >
                  </form>
```

in jquery side

i take text value and id

```
   function AddData(par){

        var artistName =  $("input[name='"+par+"']").attr('id') + '-'+$("input[name='"+par+"']").val();

        alert(artistName);

       $.post('/management/AddDataAjax2', 
        {
           data: JSON.stringify({"artistName": "artistName"})
        },
        function(response){
            alert("Başarıyla silindi");
        });
    }
```

as you see above code, when i alert i saw all needed datas

[image]

I think data does not go to  my php side

This is my php side but nothing comes

```
  public function AddDataAjax2() {

        $json = $_POST['json'];
        $data = json_decode($json, true);
        $arr = explode("-",$data);


        $personID = NCore::db('PERSON')->select('ID')->eq('NAME_SURNAME', $arr[2])->fetch(FETCH_MODEL_BASE, true);
            if($personID)
                NCore::db('PERSON_MOVIE')->insertAsArray(array('PERSON_ID' =>$personID->id,'MOVIE_ID'=> $arr[0],'JOB_ID' => $arr[1]));

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP code you need to run your code.  You have declare your function but you have not called it.  Your PHP code should look like this:

```
<?php
    AddData2Ajax2();

     public function AddDataAjax2() {

            $json = $_POST['json'];
            $data = json_decode($json, true);
            $arr = explode("-",$data);


            $personID = NCore::db('PERSON')->select('ID')->eq('NAME_SURNAME', $arr[2])->fetch(FETCH_MODEL_BASE, true);
                if($personID)
                    NCore::db('PERSON_MOVIE')->insertAsArray(array('PERSON_ID' =>$personID->id,'MOVIE_ID'=> $arr[0],'JOB_ID' => $arr[1]));

         }
?>
```

Comment: Where does you PHP code reside, is it in a file called `/management/AddDataAjax2.php`?  Where the `management` folder is in your web root folder?